# Can you make a custom view in xcode using interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, viewcontroller

not a viewcontroller, but an actual view

My app will include a piano keyboard in two separate sections. Instead of duplicating the code for each part, I'd rather make the keyboard a custom view and implement it into the respective viewcontrollers. However, itseems like it would be a pain to code the position each key, so I was hoping there was someway I could do it visually.

And if not, is there a way I could make the keyboard its own viewcontroller, and then add that as a subclass of the viewcontrollers that represent the different sections of the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you mean each piano key is a separate UIView, you could have a UIControl subclass (UIView subclass) that contains the key sub views, it would seem to me that it would be easier in you UIContol subclass to add all of the UIView subclasses for each key pragmatically because there is a nice mathematical relationship between each key you could then place your UIControl in twice in your view and set its subclass to you custom UIControl class. You could then add you individual key UIView subclasses by overriding -[UIView layoutSubviews] perhaps, you could manually add you key UIView in interface builder if you want, but the seems like a lot more work. You can have as many instances of your subclass keyboard in interface builder as you want and they don,t each have to have there own UVIewController, you Keyboard sub class can be the target of each key press from each button and then pass that onto the viewcontroller anyway you want, though I don't now how you would deal with polyphony that way if you need that,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, you can add a View class to your interface and then in under the Utilities Panel > Identity Inspector there is a custom class field which you can change to a Custom subclass of NSView.

If you want to create your own Customer fire that shows up in interface builder the search for custom IBPlugins, I haven't tried to do this with Xcode 4 so I don't know how much it has changed since Interface Builder was integrated with Xcode 4. Though this is something I have to looking got one of my own custom controls.

Comment: What I meant was that I wanted to create a custom view where instead of hard coding the drawCGRect method, I could place the subviews visually.

Comment: Ao you mean each piano key is a separate

Comment: You can add all of your keys in interface builder, then set each of their custom subclass individual